# cmake: Create a hex-file with an AVR compiler

Tags: gcc, jenkins, makefile, cmake

I hope someone is able to help me:
I try to use the cmake plugin in a jenkins server to create a hex file, but i don't know my fault.

I also try to run the example of this site: http://robot-develop.org/archives/2952 but if i use the "make" command, i get this error message:
 make: *** No targets specifed and no makefile found. Stop

Here is my code:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6.0)
INCLUDE("C:/Users/name/Desktop/example/Code/test_crosscompile.cmake")
INCLUDE("C:/Users/name/Desktop/example/Code/macro.cmake")
project (Code)
MESSAGE(STATUS "\n -------------------------------->Creating Test-Projekt...")
IF( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE )
SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release ... FORCE )
ENDIF()
SET(MAIN_FILE
    class.c)
# add the executable
add_executable(Code ${MAIN_FILE})
#makro
AVR_CREATE_HEX(class)
```

makro.cmake:

```
# create avr hex
MACRO(AVR_CREATE_HEX name)
ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${name} POST_BUILD COMMAND avr-objcopy ARGS -O ihex -R.eeprom ${name}     "C:/Users/name/Desktop/example/Code/class.hex")
MESSAGE(STATUS "\n ----------JONAS---------------------->Macro")
ENDMACRO(AVR_CREATE_HEX)
```

test_crosscompile.cmake:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "Windows")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER avr-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER avr-g++)
SET(CSTANDARD "-std=gnu99")
SET(CDEBUG "-gstabs")
SET(CWARN "-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes")
SET(CTUNING "-funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums")
SET(COPT "-Os")
SET(CMCU "-mmcu=atmega32")
SET(CDEFS "-DF_CPU=12000000UL")
SET(CFLAGS "${CMCU} ${CDEBUG} ${CDEFS} ${CINCS} ${COPT} ${CWARN} ${CSTANDARD} ${CEXTRA}")
SET(CXXFLAGS "${CMCU} ${CDEFS} ${CINCS} ${COPT}")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  ${CFLAGS})
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CXXFLAGS})
```

I use the cmake GUI, but i don't know how to use it. 
I try as generator visual studio 10 (specify toolchain file for cross compiling), but it generates no makefile or hex file. 
If i choose MinGW Makefiles as the generator, i get the error:
The C compiler "C:/WinAVR-20100110/bin/avr-gcc.exe" is not able to compile
  a simple test program.

I hope somebody can help me, THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You have the CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME set to windows, you need to set this to generic to enable Cross compiling eg:

SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)